# How to deal with unicode values dict in a column

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, apply

I have a column ('discount') in a df which every value is in its format:

```
{u'customer': u'xdawd', u'end': None, u'coupon': {u'object': u'coupon', u'name': u'Black Friday', u'percent_off': None, u'created': 213213, u'times_redeemed': 10, u'amount_off': 2500, u'currency': u'gbp', u'object': u'discount', u'start': 1543327380, u'subscription': u'uiodsjciosdj'}
```

I want to return the percent_off value or the amount_off value (only one of both appear) in a new column, so i have to get the one which is not as None in its value.

just an example of how it is in a excel:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/07h6C.png

Comment: Have you tried parsing it to String? ```python
str(value) ```

Comment: Consider switching to Python3: it has a native Unicode handling, so it makes a lot simple much things (instead of hacking on local encodings). [BTW Python2 will be very soon not more supported, and many packages do not support it anymore]: Personal opinion: it takes less time to pass to Python3 then to learn using properly ("hacking") Unicode on Python2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `lambda function` and [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df['discount'].apply(lambda x: x['coupon'].get('percent_off') or x['coupon'].get('amount_off'))
```

[out]

```
0    2500
Name: discount, dtype: int64
```

Or if you prefer to be more explicit as per @lenz suggestion:

```
def extract_discount(x):
    return x['coupon'].get('percent_off') or x['coupon'].get('amount_off') 

df['discount'].apply(extract_discount)
```

Comment: What's the benefit of writing `f = lambda x: ...` instead of `def f(x): ...`?

Comment: no benefit really, `lambda ` is just a little more succinct. `def` only required if the function is to be reused

Comment: Well, it *is* being reused, that's why need to assign it to a variable `f` so you can reference it later. Typically, linters flag this usage because you are assigning a name to a construct meant for unnamed functions. Personally, I find lambdas  harder to read than regularly defined functions.